# Inject a variable from Service to html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am asked to debug some things in an angular JS app, problem is I dont know anything about this framework and I need to get this done.

I need to inject a variable from my service to a html template.
So I thought I will need to get this variable from Controller, which get it from the Service.

For the moment I have this :

controller.js

```
$scope.fileURL = null;
var fileURL = ItemsService.fileURL;
$scope.fileURL.push(fileURL);
```

services.js

I declare this inside my service class :

```
this.fileURL = null;
```

and i declare it my method this way :

```
self.fileURL = fileURL;
```

But I got this error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of null`
And fileURL is defined and got a value in my method.
Any idea why ?

Thanks

Comment: You do `$scope.fileURL = null;` and then `$scope.fileURL.push(fileURL);` obviously `null` doesn't have method push, you need an array for that or change it to `$scope.fileURL = fileURL;`

Comment: @maurycy seems pretty logic... I tried to do $scope.fileURL = [], I don't have error now but when I use fileURL in my html it is null.

Comment: if the service is returning an object which contains fileUrl then you are better of with something like that: `$scope.itemService = ItemService` and then in partial `{{itemService.fileUrl}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**more performant solution**

Thanks to maurycy for his comments.

Making your service visible through $scope like this:

```
$scope.itemService = ItemService;
```

and using it in your template for example like this:

```
{{itemService.fileURL}}
```

will be more perfomant, less complex and have all other advantages as well.

---

**old solution**

Why don't you just pass through your variable:

In your service:

```
this.fileURL = "something";
```

in your controller:

```
$scope.fileURL = function() {
    return ItemsService.fileURL;
};
```

This way changes made in your service (like a update of fileURL will trigger an update of the view through the controller.

---

**FYI:**

If you define your $scope-variable like this:

```
Object.defineProperty($scope, 'fileURL', {
    get: function() {
        return ItemService.fileURL;
    },
    set: function(newValue) {
        ItemService.fileURL = newValue;

    }
});
```

You may also update the variable in the service from the controller **AND** childscopes will have the same functionality, since upon `$scope.fileURL = 'different';` they won't introduce a new property fileURL which hides the original one and doesn't wire to the service anymore.

Comment: and then in template use a function that will be called on every single digest... just saying

Comment: @maurycy True. Didn't think about this one. Making the service visible seems the better choice. I will update this answer.